# Svelte Sapper - Fusion chart

Tags: svelte, fusioncharts, sapper

I'm trying to use the FusionChart in sapper but not able to use it.
I following this document.
https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/sveltejs/your-first-chart-using-sveltejs

This document is for svelte so for sapper I tried few changes and tried to import the libs dynamically but still it's not working.

```
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import SvelteFC from "svelte-fusioncharts";

  $: chartConfig = {};

  onMount(async () => {
    const FusionCharts = await import("fusioncharts");
    const Charts = await import("fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts");
    const FusionTheme = await import(
      "fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion"
    );
    const { fcRoot } = await import("svelte-fusioncharts");
    fcRoot(FusionCharts, Charts, FusionTheme);

    const chartData = [
      { label: "Venezuela", value: "290" },
      { label: "Saudi", value: "260" },
      { label: "Canada", value: "180" },
      { label: "Iran", value: "140" },
      { label: "Russia", value: "115" },
      { label: "UAE", value: "100" },
      { label: "US", value: "30" },
      { label: "China", value: "30" }
    ];

    chartConfig = {
      type: "column2d", //Select the chart type
      width: 600, //Set the width of the chart
      height: 400, //Set the height of the chart
      dataFormat: "json", //Set the input dataFormat to json
      dataSource: {
        chart: {
          caption: "Countries With Most Oil Reserves [2017-18]", //Set the caption to your chart
          subCaption: "In MMbbl = One Million Barrels", //Set a sub-caption to your chart
          xAxisName: "Country", //Assign a relevant name to your x-axis
          yAxisName: "Reserves (MMbbl)", //Assign a relevant name to your y-axis
          numberSuffix: "K",
          theme: "fusion" //Apply a theme to your chart
        },
        //Include chartData from STEP 2
        data: chartData
      }
    };
  });

</script>

{#if process.browser}
  <SvelteFC {...chartConfig} />
{/if}
```

On browser, I'm getting the below error:

```
index.svelte:10 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: m is not a function
    at index.svelte:10
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at fcRoot (index.svelte:6)
    at Layout1.svelte:26
```

I'm new to svelte/sapper so may be I'm doing silly mistake somewhere.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why do you import in the onMount function instead of the top of your component?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some strange error when you try to directly import the *FusionCharts* package via `const FusionCharts = await import("fusioncharts");`. All other imports are fine. You can do a workaround. In your *template.html*, add this script in the `<head>` section:

```
<script src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
```

Then use this code to initialize the chart in your file:

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  onMount(() => {
    window.FusionCharts.ready(function () {
      // chart instance
      var chart = new FusionCharts({
        type: "column2d",
        renderAt: "chart-container", // container where chart will render
        width: "600",
        height: "400",
        dataFormat: "json",
        dataSource: {
          // chart configuration
          chart: {
            caption: "Countries With Most Oil Reserves [2017-18]",
            subcaption: "In MMbbl = One Million barrels",
          },
          // chart data
          data: [
            { label: "Venezuela", value: "290000" },
            { label: "Saudi", value: "260000" },
            { label: "Canada", value: "180000" },
            { label: "Iran", value: "140000" },
            { label: "Russia", value: "115000" },
            { label: "UAE", value: "100000" },
            { label: "US", value: "30000" },
            { label: "China", value: "30000" },
          ],
        },
      }).render();
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="chart-container" />
```

What happens is that you use the cdn instead of the npm package and add it to the global window object. It is not really the proper *svelte* way, but seems like to be your best chance at getting this up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Sapper works well with most third-party libraries you are likely to come across. However, sometimes, a third-party library comes bundled in a way which allows it to work with multiple different module loaders. Sometimes, this code creates a dependency on window, such as checking for the existence of window.global might do.

Since there is no window in a server-side environment like Sapper's, the action of simply importing such a module can cause the import to fail, and terminate the Sapper's server with an error such as:

ReferenceError: window is not defined

The way to get around this is to use a dynamic import for your component, from within the onMount function (which is only called on the client), so that your import code is never called on the server.

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    let MyComponent;

    onMount(async () => {
        const module = await import('my-non-ssr-component');
        MyComponent = module.default;
    });
</script>

<svelte:component this={MyComponent} foo="bar"/>
```

Docs - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/sveltejs/your-first-chart-using-sveltejs

```
<script>
  import FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
  import Charts from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
  import FusionTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion';
  import SvelteFC, { fcRoot } from 'svelte-fusioncharts';

  fcRoot(FusionCharts, Charts, FusionTheme);

  let dataSource = {
      "chart": {
        "caption": "Recommended Portfolio Split",
        "subCaption": "For a net-worth of $1M",
        "showValues": "1",
        "showPercentInTooltip": "0",
        "numberPrefix": "$",
        "enableMultiSlicing": "1",
        "theme": "fusion"
      },
      "data": [{
        "label": "Equity",
        "value": "300000"
      }, {
        "label": "Debt",
        "value": "230000"
      }, {
        "label": "Bullion",
        "value": "180000"
      }, {
        "label": "Real-estate",
        "value": "270000"
      }, {
        "label": "Insurance",
        "value": "20000"
      }]
    },
    chartConfig = {
      type: 'pie2d',
      width: '600',
      height: '400',
      renderAt: 'chart-container',
      dataSource
    };
</script>

<div id="chart-container" >
  <SvelteFC {...chartConfig} />
</div>
```

Please refer - https://fusioncharts.github.io/svelte-fusioncharts/